# How can HttpClientBuilder retrieve credentials for proxy authentication?

Tags: java, proxy, applet, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have developed a Java Applet that works properly in a standard environment (no proxies). On the contrary if the applet is running on a client located behind a proxy, it correctly downloads files and accedes resources with simple http GET methods (java.net) but http POST method using Apache httpclient doesn't work.
I'm using:

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
clientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = clientBuilder.build();
```

to retrieve credentials for proxy authentication (these credentials have been already used by JVM, because I can accede external resources using java.net).
The execution of the POST method results in a 407 error (Proxy authentication required). Why useSystemProperties() can't retrieve the credentials for authentication? How can I retrieve username and passoword for the proxy?

Comment: No, no fix found.